# JIRA - move one sub-task from one story to another

Tags: jira

In JIRA, how can we move one sub-task from one story to another?

Answer (score 64):

the solution is simple select the issue you need to change the parent.then navigate to more tab and select move option then there will be options to move sub-task to another parent issue. screenshot attached.

screenshot 1.

[image]

screenshot 2.

[image]

Comment: @Nayeem is this answer helped you?. It would be great if you can accept the answer if this worked for you.. :)

Comment: worked for me 6 years later :)

Comment: doesnt work for me - this move option is not available for me.

Comment: 7 years later the UI is still so bad.

Comment: The "more" option is now replaced with three dots on the top right of the subtask display page; "change parent" is under there.

Comment: The "move" option requires a certain permission. If you don't have that permission the option won't be shown in the More menu. You may still see it in the Bulk edit operation but it will be marked N/A and it will tell you explicitly that you don't have permission

Answer (score 10):

In my case, as of 2022-02-10 on a customer Jira install, that might be heavily configured to not allow things, the "move" option mentioned in another answer was not available.

I had to convert the subtask to a normal task first, then I could chose to convert the normal task to a subtask again, where I could chose the story that it should be a subtask of from all stories.
By chosing the new one then, it was "moved" from one to another with a little extra steps.